# Parallel foreach to perform threading in datatable based on row priority

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, plinq

I want to perform threading in `datatable` by filtering the rows based on priority using `Parallel foreach`

```
Priority        Name
2                A
1                B
2                C
3                D
1                E
```

Threading should be performed in the below order(Starting from priority 1 to 2,3...

Only if Priority 1 threads completes Priority 2 threads should start)

EBACD

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how or why you wan't to use `Parallel.ForEach`

It sounds like you can just use some PLINQ:

```
var result = dataTable
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(r => new { Priority = (int)r["Priority"], Name = (string)r["Name"] })
                .AsParallel()
                .OrderBy(r => r.Priority)
                .Select(r => r.Name)
                .ToList();
```

But you probably won't see much performance improvement unless you are working with millions of data rows.